# Does BPF_PROG_RUN implements the fallback ebpf interpreter?

Tags: c, interpreter, bpf, ebpf

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/33920f1ec5bf47c5c0a1d2113989bdd9dfb3fae9/include/linux/filter.h#L556-L571
is this the implementation of the  ebpf fallback interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete pchaigno's answer: The selection for `prog->bpf_func` is done by `bpf_prog_select_runtime()` defined in `kernel/bpf/core.c`, and called in `kernel/bpf/syscall.c` in `bpf_prog_load()`, i.e. when the `bpf()` system call is used with the `BPF_PROG_LOAD` command.

Selected runtime can be the in-kernel interpreter, a JIT-compiled function if JIT is in use, or a function JIT-compiled by a NIC driver in case of hardware offload.

Answer (score 1):

No, `BPF_PROG_RUN` **calls either the interpreter or the JITed program** depending on what `prog->bpf_func` points to. It also updates statistics (runtime and number of BPF executions) if the user enabled bpf stats.